# Possible to query a database into excel on a cell by cell basis? Or another solution..?

Tags: database, t-sql, excel, vba

I have various large views/stored procedures that basically churns out a lot of data into an excel spread sheet. There was a problem where not all of the
company amounts weren't flowing through.  I narrowed it down to a piece of code in a stored procedure: (Note this is cut down for simplicity)

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN view_creditrating internal_creditrating 
                        ON creditparty.creditparty = 
                           internalrating.company 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT company, contract, SUM(amount) amount 
                            FROM   COMMON_OBJ.amount 
                            WHERE  status = 'Active' 
                            GROUP  BY company, contract) col 
                       ON vd.contract = col.contract
```

Table with issue:

```
                    company  | contract | amount |
                             |          |        |
                    TVC      |   NULL   |  1006  |
                    KS       |   10070  | -2345  |
                    NYC-G    |   10060  | 334000 |
                    NYC-G    |   100216 | 4000   |
                    UECR     |   NULL   |     0  |
                    SP       |   10090  | 84356  |
```

Basically some of the contracts are NULL. So when there is a LEFT OUTER JOIN on contract the null values in contract  drop out and don't flow through...So i decided to do it based on company.
This also causes problems because company appears within the table more than once in order to show different contracts. With this change the query becomes ambiguous because it won't know if I want 
contract 10060's amount or the contract 100216's amount and more often than not it gives me the incorrect amount.  I thought about leaving the final ON clause with company = company. 
This causes the least issues.... Then Somehow directly querying for for each cell value that would be inconsistent because it only affects a few cells. Although I've searched and I don't think that this is possible. 
Is this possible?? OR is there another way to fix this on the database end?

Answer (score 1):

As you've worked out, the problem is in the `ON` clause, and its use of **NULL**.

One way to alter the **NULL** to be a value you can match against is to use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), which would alter the clause to:

```
ON coalesce(vd.contract,'No Contract') = coalesce(col.contract,'No Contract')
```

This will turn all **NULL**'s into 'No Contract', which will change the **NULL=NULL** test (which would return **NULL**) to *'No Contract'='No Contract'*, which will return *True*

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesn't work. I think is related in the example i put above for  company = company in the on clause. Now there is a bunch of No Contracts in the column which is nice but it's suppose to be a key so now the query is ambiguous and won't know which is which...which throws off the spreadsheet. Is there a way to do this on the excel side possibly? Or do you have another database idea?